# Get specific URL in Controller .NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url, asp.net-core-mvc

So this is my controller :

```
 [HttpGet("Home/Project-Name/Dashboard")]
  public IActionResult Index()
  {
    ViewBag.Current = "Dashboard";
    return View();
  }
```

The question is, how do I get the "Project-Name" Value ?

Comment: Is the idea that Index() can be called for any Project-Name, or only one specific name?

Comment: I just wanna get the project name and send it to my view to decide which navbar that i'll use, because I have a lot of navbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

Using :

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
String url = @Context.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
var uri = new Uri(url);
String url_project = uri.Segments[2].Replace(@"/", "");
```

Note that I use this code in view.

Answer (score 2):

```
var projectName = HttpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split('/',StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]
```